# chef how to overwrite attribtues in json file

Tags: attributes, chef-infra, recipe

I'm trying to run the same recipe twice with different attributes.
Is there a way to specify it in the run list?
Example:

```
"myRecipe":{
"run-list": "recipe[test], recipe[test]"
}
```

and the first one should have flag=false while second one should execute with flag=true.

Comment: You running stand chef or chef solo? Secondly, you do understand that chef is designed to be idpotent? In other words run it as many times as you like, the result should be the same. I think perhaps you desired result is best achieved using two recipes in the same cookbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You have to implement such logic in your recipe and e.g iterate over an array.

Comment: I thought so. so how about calling another recipe with a given attribute? I'm guessing that I need to first use 
override_attributes to set the attribute, then use include_recipe to call the recipe then repeat the 2 steps with a different attribute. Does this sound right?

Comment: I tried that and failed. Chef does not run a recipe twice if you include its name twice in the run_list. Any more ideas here?

Comment: Start with learnchef.com. I'm sure that you will learn the required knowledge soon. it's not easy to help you without concrete information of what you want to achieve (besides test true and test false).

Comment: Just to be helpful to some other people, I have to say that it is not possible to execute a chef recipe twice (unless you run multiple cooks). If you need to do anything twice, you'll have to do it in a script which then you can call from your recipe. This is tells me that the chef framework has significant shortcommings.

Comment: I would counter that you would just implement a loop in a recipe that e.g. iterates over an array defined in the attributes. You still did not provide details about your use case, maybe we could make it more clear to you then.

Comment: Just saw your other answer below and I think an LWRP is your way to go.

Answer (score 1):

[I answered a similar question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12547138/794374):
The short version is, you need to modify your thinking.  If you need to install software and configure it, you might do better to think about breaking it apart into two pieces.

Longer answer: have you taken a look at any of the cookbooks on the [opscode community site](http://cookbooks.opscode.com)?  Many patterns recur and work that others have published could certainly be useful... Especially as you appear to be just starting out with chef.

Comment: Its no use referring me to the opscode page since my example below is straight from their official documentation and fails as I mentioned; If you think I come to this site before trying the docs, you've massively underestimated me. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried using resources:

```
define :installx, :cmd=>'good', :upgrade=>true do
  Chef::Log.info('cmd = #{params[:cmd]}')
  if params[:upgrade]
    Chef::Log.info('upgrading...')
  else
    Chef::Log.info('installing...')
  end
end

installx resource
installx "name" do
  cmd "install 1"
  upgrade true
end
```

and it errors out: "ERROR: Cannot find a resource for define"
This is pretty much right out of the official documentation. If anyone know what's causing this, please let me know.

Comment: Ruby functions are declared with `def`, not with `define`.
I think you want two write an LWRP, that's how the pattern exactly looks like. Here is how to write a custom LWRP: http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp_custom.html

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Chef cookbook are written very well in my opinion such as the visualstudio cookbook from https://github.com/daptiv/visualstudio.

I do have a case when I need to run this recipe twice. I have to install Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 on a machine to compile different source code. These versions of Visual Studio have the exact same silent install process by point to an XML file so it was easy to make it work for 2012 and 2013.

I was able to create a Chef role file to override the attributes of the visualstudio cookbook to point my private Visual Studio 2012 ISO. That was easy. Then I created another Chef role file for installing 2013 to point to a separate Visual Studio 2013 ISO. Since Chef doesn't run the recipe twice it ends up only installing Visual Studio 2013. :(

It would suck if I have to make two local copies of the "visualstudio" cookbook.