# Chef - Visual Studio 2013 cookbook

Tags: visual-studio-2013, chef-infra, cookbook

Where can I find chef cookbook to install visual studio 2013. The chef-supermarket provides cookbook for visual studio 2012. Can it be modified to work with visual studio 2013

Comment: You can find it on `Google`.

Comment: Have you read this before posting such question? [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question . It is chef Visual Studio 2013 cookbook I am talking about . Similar to VS 2012 cookbook like this supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/visualstudio or this github.com/daptiv/visualstudio –

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: You misunderstood the SO purpose, actually.

Comment: If you don't know the answer and don't understand the question, it's not helpful to simply say "This is off topic." Unless you're a moderator and are going to close the question, move along.

Answer (score 1):

While this question is off-topic for SO, I've forked [daptiv's visualstudio cookbook](https://github.com/daptiv/visualstudio) to handle multiple versions of Visual Studio. Currently it supports 2012 and 2013. You can find the cookbook here: https://github.com/dthagard/visualstudio.

Comment: Thanks for the fork. Looks like 95% of the people that commented have no idea what Chef is.

Answer (score 0):

These are three resources you can use to help you:

Microsoft Visual Studio Installation Guide:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx

Visual Studio 2013 CookBook by Jeff Martin and Richard Banks
https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/visual-studio-2013-cookbook

A step by step tutorial to perform the installation by Mourya P.:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlhbbuFAxgQ

Hope this helps

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question . It is chef  Visual Studio 2013 cookbook I am talking about . Similar to VS 2012 cookbook like this https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/visualstudio or this https://github.com/daptiv/visualstudio

Comment: This extra post might be helpful then:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892059/chef-how-to-overwrite-attribtues-in-json-file

Comment: That's not helpful at all, @CodeRoller.